# Is there a synonym of the word "clothing" which begins with the letter "R"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there a synonym of the word "***clothing***" which begins with the letter "***R***"?

[image: a cartoon drawing of some clothing]

Comment: Rags. We're in the rag trade. My father's in women's panties. New York humor.

Comment: By *clothing*, do you mean [the participle of *to cloth*, or the participle of *to clothe*, or the adjective, or the collective noun](https://www.oed.com/search?searchType=dictionary&q=clothing&_searchBtn=Search)? If the lattermost is intended, then how many letters do you need in this *r* word? ? Your choices are a word with 7 letters dating from 1425, or with 3 or 6 letters dating from 1450, or with 8 letters from 1524, or with 9 letters from 1548, or with 7 letters from 1664, or with 3 letters from 1855 but in the singular. By the way, we aren't supposed to do crossword puzzles here. :)

Comment: @YosefBaskin That's [the 1855 solution](https://www.oed.com/view/th/class/60653) for the collective noun choices. It's also an answer that should have been entered in the Answer Box. Probably. But maybe he likes the others more. Depends on how many open boxes his puzzle has left in it.

Comment: The issue raised by @tchrist probably wouldn't have been an issue had you included a sample sentence, as the [SWR tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) directs you to do.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments it seems as if the smart guys have figured this to be a crossword question and holding back any solutions.

If it isn't, I'll suggest the word ***[raiment](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raiment)***. From M/W: "clothing, garments"